# Why does Regex hang in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have had a fairly good search around, and although there are quite a few similar questions, I don't believe the answers are applicable.

I have a reasonably inefficient regex searching a reasonably large string.  I have tested it in http://regexpal.com with the exact regex and string, and it comes back with the correct answer almost instantaneously.

The C# Regex module with the same inputs hangs - or at least I've left it 10 minutes to do what regexpal can do in fractions of a second.

Is the C# implementation of Regex hopelessly less efficient than http://regexpal.com, or is it genuinely hanging?  The regex is to search for two keywords which are separated by an unknown number of lines:

```
"KEYWORD1(.|\r|\n)+KEYWORD2\t +.+"
```

And the string is 830 lines long, each line being approximately 30 characters.

Comment: Is it faster if you remove the final `.+`?

Comment: If it is, it is not noticeable (it is still running now).

Comment: Since you're not limiting things with your `+`, it's doing a repetitive search... Look into using the `?` operator as often as possible to limit the search to the soonest occurrence wherever you have repetition (wherever you have the `+`)

Comment: Maybe give a small sample of your text and what it is you're trying to get... I think that might just be a very inefficient Regex...

Comment: @John Bustos - That's done it!  I usually do use the '?', but in this case I'd dropped it while experimenting :(  Feel free to post this as an answer.  Do you know why is regexpal quick even in spite of this?

Comment: Glad it worked!! - My GUESS is one of 2 things... 1) Either you didn't post the full text, so it had less to search. 2) You have a slightly different setting on RegexPal (like Single / Multiline kind of thing)

Comment: I've just checked, and regexpal was actually using the entire original string (about 3 times longer).  I'm not sure about the settings - C# doesn't seem to offer as many options as (say) Python - but so far regexpal has a perfect correlation with the C# regex implementation.

Comment: The .NET regex flavor (which is what C# uses) is one of the most powerful flavors out there.  It's as fast as it needs to be, and it has oodles of nice features.  But it's still sensitive to poorly written regexes, and ill-considered constructs like `(.|\s)` will make it freeze and/or crash just as they will any other flavor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation on [Regular Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `.` *matches any single character except `\n`*. This means that `.` (which doesn't match `\r` in Java (default mode), JavaScript, etc.) matches `\r` in .NET.

Your regex effectively allows 2 branches for the same character `\r`. The more `\r` in the input, the longer it takes to run the regex. On a failing input, it will cause exponential complexity based on the number of `\r` in the input.

Note that regexpal is a JavaScript regular expression tester, and as mentioned above, `.` in JavaScript excludes `\r`, `\n` (and a few other line separator). Since there is no overlap in what they match, each character has at most 1 branch to follow.

One solution is to replace `(.|\r|\n)+` with `(?s:.+)`. The `s` flag will effectively makes `.` match any character without exception. There is only one branch for any character, so no exponential backtracking.

`+.+` can't cause much inefficiency in this case, since it is already at the end of the pattern. It may cause problem (quadratic complexity) if there is something else following it, though. For example, if there is `$` at the end, then in the failing case, when the pattern  `+.+$` is matches against a suffix with lots of spaces, followed by a newline at the end, then an unoptimized engine will try all ways to divide the consecutive spaces into 2 parts.

Answer (score 2):

As was stated in the comments, a common issue with Regex is having a pattern along the lines of:

```
Word1.+Word2
```

Because if your text was very large and had something like:

```
Word1 ... Word1 ... Word2 ... Word2 ... Word1 .... Word2 ... Word2
```

You would have **ALL** combinations matched that began with `Word1` and ended with `Word2` - Even when `Word1` or `Word2` were in between them.

Generally that's not what you're looking for and want the shortest set of characters between your start and end points (or not have `Word1` show up again). For that your Regex would best be changed to:

```
Word1.+?Word2
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I believe even with `.+?` between search words, the search could end up being expensive (in CPU time), e.g. if there was no complete match but the initial word occured in lots of places -- or the final word was very short.

Comment: @wardies - Agreed! - I think maybe it could be made more efficient too, I just gave the solution based on what was given, but a VERY good point... I was thinking of something along the lines of negative lookaheads, but don't even know if that would solve this....

Comment: Both your regex will try all the cases anyway if they fail. The most `.+?` can do is to change the order of trial, so that it succeeds faster. You also change the semantic of OP's regex.

Comment: Hello @John Bustos, I hope you don't mind, but I switched the answer to nhahtdh's, as he explained the differences between C# and regexpal as well.  I VERY much appreciate your answer, as it got me past the immediate problem and allowed me to continue working.  Best regards, Mike

Answer (score -1):

Basically, your regular expression is recursive.  Removing the final `.+` solves the issue. Here is [a good article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) on avoiding it in the future.  Why does .NET hang? Probably because it will never abort the search.  Perhaps the JavaScript parser you used aborts if it detects too many steps or goes too deep into recursive searches.

Comment: `your regular expression is recursive` No, it is not.

Comment: You say removing the final `.+` solves the problem; have you tested that?  Because it has no effect in my tests, and that's just what I expected.